# Ruby on Rails: Password text field cannot recognize any text entered on it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**db.migrate files**

create.users.rb

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

add_index_to_users_email.rb

```
class AddIndexToUsersEmail < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_index :users, :email, unique: true
  end
end
```

add_password_to_diges_users.rb

```
class AddPasswordDigestToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :password_digest, :string
  end
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2023_03_09_015742) do
  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "microposts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "content"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  end

end
```

**App View of the users page**
**The form.html:**

```
<%= form_with(model: user) do |form| %>
  <% if user.errors.any? %>
    <div style="color: red">
      <h2><%= pluralize(user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% user.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="col-6 mx-auto">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                 <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <%= form.label :name, style: "display: block" %>
                        <%= form.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <%= form.label :email, style: "display: block" %>
                        <%= form.text_field :email, class: "form-control" %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <%= form.label :password, style: "display: block" %>
                        <%= form.text_field :password, class: "form-control" %>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="center">
                    <%= form.submit class: 'btn btn-outline-success' %>
                    </div>
                  </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<% end %>
```

**_user.json.jbuilder**

```
json.extract! user, :id, :name, :email, :created_at, :updated_at
json.url user_url(user, format: :json)
```

**User_test.rb**

```
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # test "the truth" do
  #   assert true
  # end

  def setup
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
      password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
    end
   
  test "should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end

  test "name should be present" do
    @user.name = " "
    assert_not @user.valid?
    end

  test "email should be present" do
    @user.email = " "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "name should not be too long" do
    @user.name = "a" * 51
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email should not be too long" do
    @user.email = "a" * 244 + "@example.com"
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email validation should accept valid addresses" do
    valid_addresses = %w[user@example.com USER@foo.COM A_US-ER@foo.bar.org
    
    first.last@foo.jp alice+bob@baz.cn]
    
    valid_addresses.each do |valid_address|
    @user.email = valid_address
    assert @user.valid?, "#{valid_address.inspect} should be valid"
    end
  end

  test "email addresses should be unique" do
    duplicate_user = @user.dup
    @user.save
    assert_not duplicate_user.valid?
  end

  test "email addresses should be saved as lower-case" do
    mixed_case_email = "Foo@ExAMPle.CoM"
    @user.email = mixed_case_email
    @user.save
    assert_equal mixed_case_email.downcase, @user.reload.email
  end
end
```

When I tried to make a user with a password, just to see, if the validations do work: It would recognize the name and email, however, even if I have already entered a password such as this: `sample_password1234`, an error will show even if the password is not blank:

```
Password can't be blank
Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)
```

It does work on the console sandbox thought:
[image]

**User controller**
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_user, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

```
  # GET /users or /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1 or /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users or /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to user_url(@user), notice: "User was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1 or /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to user_url(@user), notice: "User was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1 or /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: "User was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  #show micropost for the user
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @micropost = @user.microposts.first
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
    end
end
```

**Update:**

After adding the password on user params, does this mean that this works already?

[image]

However, if I will try user.password, it will show a 'nil'

[image]

Comment: Your permitted params have only name and email.

Comment: @DaveNewton Hello, can you check my post again? I tried adding it password on the permitted params, however, I am not sure if it is fully working already. It does show that the password_digest is already there and saved on the db. But then when I tried, user.password, it will show a `nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dave already wrote, you have to add the password attributes to the strong params in the controller like this:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Without that adding those attributes names to the strong params the user input will not be passed to the model and therefore the password will not be set.

That you cannot read the password later is for security reasons. When the password and the password confirmation match, then Ruby on Rails will generate a password digest and store that digest in the database. Ruby on Rails does not store the password itself and therefore cannot return it. Only the digest is stored. The digest can be used to check if an entered password is the same as the original password, but it cannot be used to return the original password.